# libvlc-qt error while executing the example project

Tags: c++, qt, vlc, libvlc

i'm using qt5 and ubuntu 13.04

i clone the git repository (git clone git://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt.git) and i follow the steps written in the readme, this is the output:

```
tdsxv@tdsxv-M52S-S3P:~/VLCLibrary$ mkdir build
tdsxv@tdsxv-M52S-S3P:~/VLCLibrary$ cd build/
tdsxv@tdsxv-M52S-S3P:~/VLCLibrary/build$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=prefix
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:615 (message):
  /usr/bin/qmake reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu" but
  QtCore could not be found there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the
  target build environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:92 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found unsuitable Qt version "5.0.1" from /usr/bin/qmake
VLC-Qt: Build with Qt5
VLC-Qt: Build with Widgets: ON
VLC-Qt: Build with QML: OFF
VLC-Qt: Build statically: OFF
-- Found LibVLC include-dir path: /usr/include
-- Found LibVLC library path:/usr/lib/libvlc.so
-- Found LibVLCcore library path:/usr/lib/libvlccore.so

VLC-Qt: You are compiling libvlc-qt 0.9.0

-- Git Version Patch: 8fb8b88

VLC-Qt: Build tests: OFF

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build
tdsxv@tdsxv-M52S-S3P:~/VLCLibrary/build$ make
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary -B/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target vlc-qt_automoc
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 24
[  4%] Automoc for target vlc-qt
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_automoc /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/
Generating moc_Audio.cpp
Generating moc_Instance.cpp
Generating moc_Media.cpp
Generating moc_MediaList.cpp
Generating moc_MediaListPlayer.cpp
Generating moc_MediaPlayer.cpp
Generating moc_Video.cpp
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  24
[  4%] Built target vlc-qt_automoc
make -f src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 1
[  8%] Generating qrc_logo.cpp
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/rcc -name logo -o /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/qrc_logo.cpp /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/data/logo.qrc

...

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 14
[ 62%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/VideoMemoryStream.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/usr/include/vlc/plugins -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/VideoMemoryStream.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core/VideoMemoryStream.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 15
[ 66%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/qrc_logo.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/usr/include/vlc/plugins -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/qrc_logo.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/qrc_logo.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 16
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/vlc-qt_automoc.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DVLCQT_CORE_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/usr/include/vlc/plugins -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/vlc-qt_automoc.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/vlc-qt_automoc.cpp
Linking CXX shared library libvlc-qt.so
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC  -fPIE   -shared -Wl,-soname,libvlc-qt.so.0.9 -o libvlc-qt.so.0.9.0 CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/Audio.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/Common.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/Enums.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/Error.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/Instance.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/Media.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/MediaList.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/MediaListPlayer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/MediaPlayer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/MetaManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/Video.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/VideoFrame.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/VideoMemoryStream.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/qrc_logo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/vlc-qt_automoc.cpp.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.0.1 -lvlc -lvlccore 
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_symlink_library libvlc-qt.so.0.9.0 libvlc-qt.so.0.9 libvlc-qt.so
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
[ 70%] Built target vlc-qt
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target vlc-qt-widgets_automoc
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 23
[ 75%] Automoc for target vlc-qt-widgets
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_automoc /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/
Generating moc_ControlAudio.cpp
Generating moc_ControlVideo.cpp
Generating moc_WidgetSeek.cpp
Generating moc_WidgetVideo.cpp
Generating moc_WidgetVolumeSlider.cpp
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  23
[ 75%] Built target vlc-qt-widgets_automoc
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target vlc-qt-widgets
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 17
[ 79%] Building CXX object src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/ControlAudio.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DVLCQT_WIDGETS_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_widgets_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/ControlAudio.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets/ControlAudio.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 18
[ 83%] Building CXX object src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/ControlVideo.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DVLCQT_WIDGETS_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_widgets_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/ControlVideo.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets/ControlVideo.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 19
[ 87%] Building CXX object src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetSeek.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DVLCQT_WIDGETS_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_widgets_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetSeek.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets/WidgetSeek.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 20
[ 91%] Building CXX object src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetVideo.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DVLCQT_WIDGETS_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_widgets_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetVideo.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets/WidgetVideo.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 21
[ 95%] Building CXX object src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetVolumeSlider.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DVLCQT_WIDGETS_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_widgets_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetVolumeSlider.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets/WidgetVolumeSlider.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 22
[100%] Building CXX object src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.cpp.o
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SHARED -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DVLCQT_WIDGETS_LIBRARY -D_REENTRANT -Dvlc_qt_widgets_EXPORTS -fPIE -fPIC -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets -I/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++    -o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.cpp.o -c /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.cpp
Linking CXX shared library libvlc-qt-widgets.so
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC  -fPIE   -shared -Wl,-soname,libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9 -o libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9.0 CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/ControlAudio.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/ControlVideo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetSeek.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetVideo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/WidgetVolumeSlider.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.cpp.o  -L/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.0.1 -lvlc-qt /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.0.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.0.1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core: 
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_symlink_library libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9.0 libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9 libvlc-qt-widgets.so
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  17 18 19 20 21 22
[100%] Built target vlc-qt-widgets
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 0
tdsxv@tdsxv-M52S-S3P:~/VLCLibrary/build$ make install
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary -B/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 24
[  4%] Automoc for target vlc-qt
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_automoc /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt_automoc.dir/
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  24
[  4%] Built target vlc-qt_automoc
make -f src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/core /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/build.make src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make[2]: Nessuna operazione da eseguire per "src/core/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt.dir/build".
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
[ 70%] Built target vlc-qt
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 23
[ 75%] Automoc for target vlc-qt-widgets
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_automoc /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets_automoc.dir/
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  23
[ 75%] Built target vlc-qt-widgets_automoc
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
cd /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make -f src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/build.make src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make[2]: Nessuna operazione da eseguire per "src/widgets/CMakeFiles/vlc-qt-widgets.dir/build".
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles  17 18 19 20 21 22
[100%] Built target vlc-qt-widgets
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/CMakeFiles 0
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
make[1]: Nessuna operazione da eseguire per "preinstall".
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build"
Install the project...
/usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so.0.9.0
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so.0.9
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt.so
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Audio.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Common.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Enums.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Error.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Instance.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Media.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/MediaList.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/MediaListPlayer.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/MediaPlayer.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/MetaManager.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/SharedExportCore.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Video.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/VideoDelegate.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/VideoFrame.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/VideoMemoryStream.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/Config.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9.0
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so
-- Removed runtime path from "/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9.0"
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/ControlAudio.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/ControlVideo.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/SharedExportWidgets.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/WidgetSeek.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/WidgetVideo.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt/WidgetVolumeSlider.h
-- Installing: /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/lib/pkgconfig/libvlc-qt.pc
tdsxv@tdsxv-M52S-S3P:~/VLCLibrary/build$
```

then i open the example (demo-player) with qtcreator. i compile it but when i try to execute i get the error:

```
Starting /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/examples/demo-player-Debug/src/demo-player...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/examples/demo-player-Debug/src/demo-player exited with code 0
```

if i try to run it in debug mode i getthe error:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault
```

this is the .pro file:

```
TARGET      = demo-player
TEMPLATE    = app

QT          += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES     += main.cpp\
               DemoPlayer.cpp

HEADERS     += DemoPlayer.h

FORMS       += DemoPlayer.ui

#LIBS        += -lvlc-qt -lvlc-qt-widgets

# Edit below for custom library location
LIBS     += -L/home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt -lvlc-qt -lvlc-qt-widgets
INCLUDEPATH += /home/tdsxv/VLCLibrary/build/prefix/include/vlc-qt
```

why this program doesn't work?

Comment: It's crashing, that's why. You'll need to run a debugger on it. Also, you may need to compile everything with debug information to actually trace down the bug.

Comment: @JohnChadwick How to run libvlc-qt on windows? DO you have any guide or steps illustrating the process?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. However, this comments section may be a bad place to discuss this. Why not try to do it and when you come up on an issue, post it to SO?

Answer (score 1):

For all newcomers from the internet, to save their time.

When you install libvlc-qt* using *apt-get* then you will have library compiled with QT4 (it is by default).
And the problem is that your app trying to use both QT4 and QT5 at the same time.
My solution:

1. `sudo aptitude install qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev  qt5-qmake libqt5opengl5-dev libqt5gui5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt5location5 libqt5core5a libqt53d5`
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily`
   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo aptitude install vlc vlc-data`
   `sudo aptitude install libvlc-dev libvlccore-dev`
3. Download source of the vlc-qt library from official git reporitory https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt
   and build it yourself with QT5 and run `make install`
4. `sudo ldconfig -v`
   **[ldconfig](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_ldconfi.htm)** creates the necessary links and cache (for use by the run-time linker, ld.so) to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/usr/lib and /lib).
5. Rebuild the module cache which was outdated an pointing to Qt4 binaries. You can reset it on the command line:

   ```
    sudo /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/
   ```

   Or pass to vlc the option:

   ```
   --reset-plugins-cache
   ```

After these steps it worked at last.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps while installing vlc qt:

- `git clone git://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt.git`
- `git submodule init`
- `git submodule update`

then follow below steps:

- `sudo apt-get libvlc-dev`
- `sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev`
- `sudo apt-get install libvlccore-dev`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev libvlccore-dev libvlc-dev`
- `sudo cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`
- `sudo make -j8`
- `sudo make install`

**The issue I have faced earlier:**

```
 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick"
  (requested version 5.2.0) with any of the following names:

    Qt5QuickConfig.cmake
    qt5quick-config.cmake
```

Comment: I feel like this answer is a bit unclear. Could you please provide more details on what the issue is and how your answer resolves it? Perhaps you could also take a glance at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).